# How to remove a varying part from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, string, replace

```
let: string str = 
"a=<random text>
 a=pattern:<random text (may be fixed length)>
 a=<random text>";
```

Suppose, from above string `a=` and `pattern` are fixed. There may or may not be `\n` after each line.
How to remove `a=pattern:<random>` from the `str` string?

Comment: How is the `pattern:*` terminated? e.g. any whitespace

Comment: If you match it via whitespace, then you can still allow for a fallthrough via adding support for quotes. I've created a RegExr playground https://regexr.com/6hobs

Comment: @sno2, for now assume that the `pattern:*` ends with a `\na=`. BTW, the `pattern:<random text>` doesn't have any single/quotes. For future users, it will be good to post such answer.

Comment: Perhaps like this? `^\s*a=pattern:.*(?:\n(?!\s*a=).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/GgNM17/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex capturing groups. Capture the text before and after the text you want to remove.

```
let newStr = str.replace(/(a=.+(\n)?)(a=pattern:.+)((\n)?a=.+)/, "$1$4")
```

Comment: Good answer. BTW, when I run this code, the tailing `\n` is still remaining. How to remove that. See the [demo here](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xwj7j7pd).

Comment: If you are asking how to remove a possible trailing `\n`, you could capture that too by adding another `(\n)?` to the end of that RegEx. You would be left with something like this: `let newStr = str.replace(/(a=.+(\n)?)(a=pattern:.+)((\n)?a=.+)(\n)?/, "$1$4")`